# The requested resource () is not available0 in spring mvc mongodb

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I'm newbie in Spring data mongodb. I got that error in tomcat when I run my project. Cannot figure out where is the problem. Can anyone help me

Here is my code:

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.alfred" />

    <!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    </bean>

    <!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and quering the documents in the database -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="StudentManagement" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" /> 

</beans>
```

**My controller**

```
    package com.alfred.controller;

import com.alfred.dao.StudentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 *
 * @author jmangovn
 */
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String getAllStudent(ModelMap model) {  
        model.addAttribute("allStudent", studentService.getListStudent());  
        return "output";  
    }  

}
```

**output.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <c:forEach var="student" items="${allStudent}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${student.fullName}</td><td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**StudentService**

```
package com.alfred.dao;

import com.alfred.model.Student;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public class StudentService implements StudentDAO { 
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Student> getListStudent() {
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(Student.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student.ClassInfo> findByDistinctClass() {
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(Student.ClassInfo.class);
//        return mongoTemplate.getCollection("Students").distinct("class_id");
    }

//        public List<Student.ClassInfo> findByDistinct(String key) {
//        return mongoTemplate.findAll(Student.ClassInfo.class);
//        return mongoTemplate.getCollection("Students").distinct(key);
//    }
    @Override
    public List<Student> getListStudentByClass(String classId) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("class").is(
        Query.query(
                Criteria.where("class_id").is(classId)).getQueryObject()));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Student.class);
    }

}
```

**After add @Controller in my controller, I got another error**

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:323)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1719)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.alfred.dao.StudentService com.alfred.controller.StudentController.studentService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.alfred.dao.StudentService field com.alfred.controller.StudentController.studentService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:323)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1719)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.alfred.dao.StudentService com.alfred.controller.StudentController.studentService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.alfred.dao.StudentService field com.alfred.controller.StudentController.studentService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:323)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1719)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.alfred.dao.StudentService field com.alfred.controller.StudentController.studentService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:323)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1719)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:7
```

44)

Comment: What url are you hitting that gives the error?

Comment: where does output.jsp sit in the project?

Comment: output.jsp locate in WEB-INF/jsp. And my URL is http://localhost:8080/SpringMongo/student

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `@Controller` annotation on `StudentController` class because if you don't the `StudentController` will not be recognized by Spring.

Comment: What error? Check your request mapping and also add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to the dispatcher-servlet.xml. What URL are you typing in browser and what is the root url of your project?

Comment: @FlyingDumpling I think we are going to tag team this one!  His controller wasn't getting picked up and after that the `@RequestMapping` annotation wasn't configured.

Comment: I've updated error in my question. I added <mvc:annotation-driven/> in dispatch-serlvet.xml following @Kevin Bosersox but still got an error as I mentioned in my question

Comment: Is the `StudentService` annotated with `@Service`?

Comment: @user3027246 Generally I see that don't quite understand how Spring is working. It's all about dependency injection. Without it Spring cannot do its "magic". You must use DI in order to get things work. To use DI you must tell Spring that a class is ready to be a Spring component and then you can wire your components together. You do this either by xml or by annotations. Spring MVC prefers annotation config. For a class to be a Spring component you must annotate it with one of the following: `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component`. Then to wire your components use `@Autowired`

Comment: I updated my question above with my StudentService. Actually, my student services have @Reposity annotation

Comment: Change `studentService` filed type to `StudentDAO` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` in combination with the `@Controller` suggested by Flying Dumpling.

> `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` registers a RequestMappingHandlerMapping,
>   a RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, and an
>   ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver (among others) in support of
>   processing requests with annotated controller methods using
>   annotations such as @RequestMapping, @ExceptionHandler, and others.